# Could Doctor Strange bring this character back to life using the Time Stone?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame, avengers-infinity-war

I would like to know if it's possible that Doctor Strange could bring the decapitated Thanos on the planet Titan 2 back to life by reversing time with the Time Stone.

Consider that in the movie *Avengers: Infinity War* Thanos was able to bring Vision back to life using the Time Stone so he could take the Mind Stone from Vision.

Comment: I'd say no. Some deaths seem to be final. See: The Ancient One and [spoiler alert] Tony Stark.

Comment: No.. for three reasons: 1. Time stone was reduced to atoms, 2. Strange was reduced to dust, 3. If 1 and 2 are ignored, why would he bring Thanos back? he would just use the time stone to bring back the other stones.

Comment: @Shreedhar, perhaps he might bring him back to get some important information about the past that only Thanos would know. After he's done getting this information from Thanos he could use the Time Stone to forward time again and Thanos would be dead again.

Comment: @user255577 do you think Thanos, Who was willing to sacrifice his daughter and his life included to save the universe could give away such crucial info to the only people who are going to reverse what he did?

Comment: @Shreedhar, well, Thanos may be willing to tell Dr. Strange what he wants to know if Thor and the Avengers are there with him, and Thor is threatening to cut his head off again if Thanos doesn't give them the information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you could get the Time Stone, Doctor Strange and Thanos' body all in the same place (presumably after the events of Endgame [when the alternate Time stone was in Cap's possession and Stephen Strange was restored to life](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zhzml.jpg)), there's **absolutely no reason he couldn't use the Benatar to travel to Planet 0259-S, then use the stone to reverse Thor's cut and return Thanos to life.**

As you've said, Thanos was able to use the Time Stone reverse time and restore Vision to life, by the same token Strange has shown a capacity to reverse time in precisely the same way.

[image]

Of course, it's fairly likely that shortly after doing so, Thanos would resume his quest for the Infinity Stones (and murder the population of Earth on the way), so it's relatively unlikely that Doctor Strange would want to do so, unless there was an overriding reason for it, nor that the other Avengers (and Guardians) would allow him to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Could he? Most likely. The Time Stone could reverse damage to life as we see with him practicing on the apple in *Doctor Strange* as well as the reverse scene in Hong Kong and you could also argue the time loop against Dormammu. Another example, as you state, being Vision in *Avengers: Infinity War*. However, the only difference here is they were all done almost immediately but that shouldn’t matter.

There are, however, a few caveats to this:

#### Doctor Strange was absent

As we know from the events of *Avengers: Infinity War* Doctor Strange was one of the Vanished. As such he wasn’t around to be able to do it even if he wanted to.

#### The Time Stone was destroyed

When Doctor Strange was around after the fact there was only a brief window after the Battle of Earth where Strange could have used the Stones before Steve took them back. The Avengers most likely wouldn’t have used any of the Stones at all either, they’ve seen the destruction they can bring and they are all against that.

#### Why would he anyway?

Strange sacrifices the Time Stone for Tony’s life and gave up his own life for the eventual outcome of beating Thanos. Why would he then bring him back to life? He wouldn’t.

Comment: the only reason I can see bringing Thanos back to life, perhaps only for a short time, would to get some key information about the past that only Thanos would know about, if a future Avengers movie plot were to call for it. Dr. Strange would then use the Time Stone to forward time and Thanos would be decapitated again.

Comment: @user255577 _"to get some key information about the past that only Thanos would know about"_ - That doesn't make sense, Thanos isn't just going to give that information up and for all that effort it would just be easier to use the Time Stone to view the past.

Comment: @ TheLethalCarrot, that's a good point.

Comment: @user255577 You really think Strange would need Thanos when he had the Time Stone? Whatever the mystery is, Strange could just go/look back in time and figure it out himself.